# PinterestLikeAdapter items order

Tags: android, layout

I am facing a problem constructing a grid using the following library :

https://github.com/chenyoca/pinterest-like-adapter-view

I configured it to use 3 columns. The problem I'm having is that it starts filling the Grid by the middle of the columns (the second one) so it ends disordered.

Did anyone face this problem with this library? 
Thanks.

Ps: please don't suggest to use StaggeredGridView as it resulted very buggy for me.

Answer (score 0):

Write a Comparator for your objects that sorts on the field you want.  Then before passing the arraylist to the adapter, call

```
Collections.sort(mItemList,new MyItemComparator());
```

For example, here is a comparator I use to sort documents by their version time.

```
public static class DocumentVersionTimeComparator implements Comparator<Document> {
    private boolean mDescending;

    public DocumentVersionTimeComparator(boolean descending) {
        mDescending = descending;
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(Document right, Document left) {
        if (mDescending) {
            return ((Long) left.getVersionTime()).compareTo((Long) right.getVersionTime());

        } else {
            return ((Long) right.getVersionTime()).compareTo((Long) left.getVersionTime());
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm afraid the list is ordered itself but the component is showing disordered. It starts filling from the second column instead the first one.